# Why does emacs show these warnings and errors?

Tags: c, emacs, flycheck

I am trying to make the switch to Emacs from VIM but I am having trouble getting the syntax checkers to work for a small C project.  I have tried both Flymake and Flycheck as syntax checkers and both show a non-existent compiler error. I currently have 3 files, `poker.c` `cards.c` and `cards.h`.

here is poker.c

```
#include "cards.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

  struct Deck *deck = malloc(sizeof(struct Deck)); 
  struct Hand *hand = malloc(sizeof(struct Hand));
   clear_deck(deck);
  deck = init_deck(deck);
  deck = shuffle(deck);
  int c = deal(deck, hand);
  if(c != 5) {
    printf("error: not enough cards delt");
  } else {
    print_hand(hand);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and this is cards.h

```
typedef enum {
  TWO,
  THREE,
  FOUR,
  FIVE,
  SIX,
  SEVEN,
  EIGHT,
  NINE,
  TEN,
  JACK,
  QUEEN,
  KING,
  ACE,
} Rank;


typedef enum {
  SPADES,
  CLUBS,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS,
} Suit;

struct Card {
  Rank rank;
  Suit suit;
  int shuffled;
};

struct Deck {
  struct Card cards[52];
  int shuffled;
};

struct Hand{
  struct Card cards[5];
};

void * shuffle(struct Deck *deck);
void * init_deck(struct Deck *d);
void clear_deck(struct Deck *d);
void print_deck(struct Deck *d);
void print_hand(struct Hand *h);
int deal(struct Deck *deck, struct Hand *hand);
```

Both syntax checkers show an error for the line

```
  struct Hand *hand = malloc(sizeof(struct Hand));
```

as well as warnings for all the other functions.  Here is the `*Flycheck errors*` buffer

```
    9  37 error           invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct Hand’... (c/c++-gcc)
   10   4 warning         implicit declaration of function ‘clear_deck’... (c/c++-gcc)
   11   3 warning         implicit declaration of function ‘init_deck’... (c/c++-gcc)
   11   8 warning         assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast... (c/c++-gcc)
   12   3 warning         implicit declaration of function ‘shuffle’... (c/c++-gcc)
   12   8 warning         assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast... (c/c++-gcc)
   13   3 warning         implicit declaration of function ‘deal’... (c/c++-gcc)
   17   5 warning         implicit declaration of function ‘print_hand’... (c/c++-gcc)
```

I feel like that emacs isn't running the C pre processor before doing the syntax checking.  Is there something I can do about this to make the syntax checker work properly?

Comment: have you told emacs to include the cards.h file (as in where to find it)?

Comment: have you added this to your init.el file: '(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)'?  Is the cards.h file in a emac buffer when checking poker.c?

Comment: which 'syntax checker' have you told flycheck to use for .c and .h files?

Comment: for the syntax checker: c/c++-gcc,  there is the options: flycheck-gcc-args which you can use to tell gcc -I<pathToIncludeFiles>

Answer (score -1):

amongst other things, the header file: cards.h, needs to have a 'include guard'   suggest

```
#ifndef CARDS_H
#define CARDS_H

typedef enum {
  TWO,
  THREE,
  FOUR,
  FIVE,
  SIX,
  SEVEN,
  EIGHT,
  NINE,
  TEN,
  JACK,
  QUEEN,
  KING,
  ACE,
} Rank;


typedef enum {
  SPADES,
  CLUBS,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS,
} Suit;

struct Card {
  Rank rank;
  Suit suit;
  int shuffled;
};

struct Deck {
  struct Card cards[52];
  int shuffled;
};

struct Hand{
  struct Card cards[5];
};

void * shuffle(struct Deck *deck);
void * init_deck(struct Deck *d);
void clear_deck(struct Deck *d);
void print_deck(struct Deck *d);
void print_hand(struct Hand *h);
int deal(struct Deck *deck, struct Hand *hand);

#endif // CARDS_H
```

I compiled the file: poker.c
with additions for error checking.

With all warnings enabled (linux ubuntu 14.04 and gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ...)

it cleanly compiled.

Here is the code I compiled.

```
#include "cards.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct Deck *deck = malloc(sizeof(struct Deck)); 
    if( NULL == deck )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for deck failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    struct Hand *hand = malloc(sizeof(struct Hand));
    if( NULL == hand )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror("malloc for hand failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    clear_deck(deck);
    deck = init_deck(deck);
    deck = shuffle(deck);
    int c = deal(deck, hand);

    if(c != 5) 
    {
        printf("error: not enough cards delt\n"); // \n so will immediate be output

    } 

    else 
    {
        print_hand(hand);
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: this did not fix the problem, I already know the program is valid as it compiles and runs as expected.  My question is more specific to flycheck and emacs than the C code